# how can I obtain certain data from a web UI on my LAN

Tags: wget

I have tried using WGET to grab data off the web UI from my newly installed boiler/HW tank for analysis. I believe it uses JAVA and WGET will only save the first page (that doesn't contain anything useful). I'd like to write some sort of script that access's these pages, finds the appropriate part of the page and copies the relevant data to a CS text file for later importing into libreoffice. My programming experience is limited and very old, basic, pascal, cobol etc. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this? I'm sure there are uses that would create something easily, pointers in the right direction, I'd like to learn. Currently I access said web page, select appropriate page and write the figures down. I never have exact 24 hours and often forget. Something that runs in Cron would be fantastic.

Comment: Hard to say much from what little you posted some web crawler perhaps.

Comment: If you can write small Python, I would recommend scrapy.. Go through the basics - list, dictionary, for loops.. You can simplify your life by a small dosage of snake medicine

Comment: yeah, not much to go on, but another couple tools are mechanize (ruby), and PhantomJS (javascript). Doing this with only curl and shell scripting would be more difficult IMO.  

https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize  

http://phantomjs.org/